# How to write these quantum systems in vector form

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, vectors, quantum-computer

I have been given these three quantum states:

1: $\frac{1}{\sqrt8}(|0\rangle +|1\rangle)(|0\rangle +|1\rangle) (|0\rangle +|1\rangle)|11\rangle$

2: $\frac{1}{2}(|0\rangle +|1\rangle)(|0\rangle +|1\rangle) |111\rangle$

and

3: $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle +|1\rangle)|1111\rangle$

---

Taking State $1$ as an example:

From what I understand is that for state $1$ it is a 2 qubit system so in vector form it would be represented like:

$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
        0  \\
        0  \\
        0  \\
        1  \\
        \end{matrix}
\right] 
$

This would be the equivalent of: $0|00\rangle + 0|01\rangle+0|10\rangle+1|11\rangle$

But how I would represent state $1$ as given abovein vector form? Is it just notation I am getting confused with? So for example it could mean that it is a 2-qubit system where the first three components are $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}|00\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt2}|01\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}|10\rangle+0|11\rangle$

So using this, state $1$ in vector notation is actually the following?

$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
        1  \\
        1  \\
        1  \\
        0  \\
        \end{matrix}
\right] = 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
        0.7071  \\
        0.7071  \\
        0.7071  \\
        0  \\
        \end{matrix}
\right]
$

I'm not saying the above is correct but is it something along those lines or is there something I am missing as I am unclear as to how the above states could be represented in vector notation or even in just a more simpler notation such as in the form $|00\rangle + |01\rangle+ |10\rangle+ |11\rangle$

I am still very new to quantum computing and all its notation so any explanation or advice is appreciated!

Comment: It seems things would be easier if you tried first to clearly identify what is $\vert 0\rangle$ and what is $\vert 1\rangle$ in terms of column vectors, or what is $\vert 0\rangle+\vert 1\rangle$ and $\vert 11\rangle$ etc. in terms of column vectors.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I'm not sure I understand you but even if you could help me understand how to translate those given states into a clearer and easier to understand form such as $a|00\rangle + b|01\rangle+ c|10\rangle+ d|11\rangle$

Comment: First note that each of those involve 5 qubits. So how many basis states will the system have?

Comment: @BuddyJohn So are you saying each 1,2 and 3 are all 5 qubit systems? Would you mind explaining? This would be there would be 32 basis states

Comment: @Catherine Yep! So start with state as initially written and just multiply them out. Then take the coefficients for each basis state (many will be zero) and put them into a vector with 32 entries (one for each basis state).

Comment: Once you see what is going on when multiplying it out, you may find that you can skip writing it all out. But it is at least handy to start that way.